# .htaccess 301 redirect of a dynamic url with defined first part and random last part

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, random

I'm new to this, so i searched and could also do alot alone. But now there's a point I need your help. It's about a e-commerce page.

I want to redirect the old URLs from our brand pages to the new one.

The old brand URLs looks like:
`http://www.domain.com/index.php?shop_q=empty&cid=0&man=32&pf=0.00&pt=10000.00&p=shop&action=showproducts&list=date_asc&limit=10`

the only thing i need out of this long url is man=32, what stands for the manufacturer (brand) id.

the new URL looks like:
`http://domain.com/brand/8_brand-name`

So I want that the rule to redirect every url with man=32 in it to the new brand URL, even if there are more characters in the URL.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)man=32($|&)
RewriteRule ^ /brand/8_brand-name? [L,R=301]
```

The condition's regex pattern, `(^|&)man=32($|&)`, matches a specific query string parameter, and will match it no matter where in the query string it is.

Comment: Did you miss `?` at the end of the target URL?

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted and it works fine. Thank you very much Jon Lin!